# How to dynamically select the input radio when you edit an item on the form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form with 2 different categories (radio input), that each of them has its own inputs. Now I need to add an "edit" functionality, I couldn't find out how to show the proper edited form because the radio input always refer to the last selected category (I need to manually switch, then I will see the content of the form which I need to edit). How to solve this the angular2 way? (I am new with angular)

This is how the form set up:

```
<form #formRef="ngForm" novalidate>
  <div>
    <label for="fruits">
      <input type="radio" name="fruits"
      [(ngModel)]="toggleFormType" #toggleFormTypeRef="ngModel" checked
      >
      Fruits
    </label>
    <label for="vegetables">
      <input type="radio" name="vegetables"
      [(ngModel)]="toggleFormType" #toggleFormTypeRef="ngModel" checked
      >
      Vegetables
    </label>
  </div>

  <fieldset 
  ngModelGroup="fruits" *ngIf="toggleFormType === 'fruits'">
    // Inputs for fruits
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset 
  ngModelGroup="vegetables" *ngIf="toggleFormType === 'vegetables'">
    // Inputs for fruits
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Later on I have `ngFor` to show the items:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of fruits; let i = index">
  {{item.fruit.name}}
  <a href="#" (click)="editItem(item, i)">
</li>

<li *ngFor="let item of vegetables; let i = index">
  {{item.vegetable.name}}
  <a href="#" (click)="editItem(item, i)">
</li>
```

When I hit the `editItem` I could see that everything works fine (I could see the pre content & save it with the new one), the only thing I am missing is that I need to switch the proper `category`. I need it to show the proper `category` which is the category of the edited item. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you expecting? that one category is preselected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! All I needed was to "set" the state on the `toggleFormType`. Something like this

```
public editItem (event: Event, item: any, i: number) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.editModeIsOn = true;
  this.index = i;

  if (item.type === "fruit") {
    this.fruit = item.fruit;
    this.toggleFormType = item.type;
  } else {
    this.vegetable = item.vegetable;
    this.toggleFormType = item.type;
  }
  this.setView("form");
}
```